# Convert PDF to SVG in Flutter/Dart

Tags: pdf, flutter, svg, dart, type-conversion

I want to convert a PDF to SVG, to later show it. I am using Dart and I don't know if possible with this new language.

Comment: Could you provide any examples or researches you try it?

Comment: Why not just show the PDF? Why go to SVG? SVG cannot handle everything that can be in a PDF, such as a bunch of blend modes, cmyk, and much more.

Comment: Maybe cause its hard to display pdfs at flutter windows applications :(